# Can JavaFX be used for building UI part in Java EE applications?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javafx

Just curious. I am still beginner in Java EE world. As I have read, JavaFX allows building nice looking, rich client applications. And that in future it should replace Swing applications. That sounds normal knowing that JavaFX offers many new features than Swing, and also can cooperate with Swing.

But, can JavaFX application be used in Java EE application? How to combine JavaFX with Java EE beans, entities, persistence to database, web services ...? If anybody have some example of some JavaFX Java EE application, I would be glad to take a look at application structure.

Comment: I can't see why not. Jee is not necessarily jsp/servlet/jsf

Comment: JavaFX is still very fresh, and on the desktop there are some additional third party (open source) libraries to provide needed GUI extensions. So personally I would not risk it for production, do a bit of research first.

Comment: http://www.guigarage.com/2013/05/designing-javafx-business-applications-part-1/

Comment: I would use it, but do the research as Joop Eggen says. Also the `WebView` component provides interesting possibilities for hybrid web-desktop applications. And the usage of CSS from JavaFX makes it possible to apply the same sort of styling in the web and desktop parts. Also check out [this](https://github.com/in-sideFX/iBreed)

Answer (score 0):

There are many frameworks to integrate JavaFX with a JEE backend.

You should take a look at Granite Data Services as it supports JEE beans, JPA entities, bean validation, lazy-loading and much more (JMS, real-time communications...).

https://www.granitedataservices.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this presentation will help:

video: https://www.parleys.com/talk/enterprise-javafx

slides: http://de.slideshare.net/HendrikEbbers/javafx-enterprise-javaone-2014

Comment: Can DataFX provide a tool a communication between JavaFX application (Client side) and other Language Server side ?